# Table-valued parameter, SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a table type in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
CREATE TYPE NameResourceType AS TABLE
(
   ID int, 
   [Value] Varchar(256) 
)
```

but I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

I don't know why, because it is 100% correct and also TVP (table-valued parameter) is a feature of SQL Server 2008.

What's the problem?

Comment: yeah, it seems correct to me :\

Comment: Yes, it is correct. I just execute your statement, it works.

Comment: The version of Management Studio is irrelevant. It is the version of the server that you are connected to that is important. What does `SELECT @@VERSION` say?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to create a table type in sql server 2008 Management Studio

That is not enough if you want to use TVP. You have to connect to  a SQL Server 2008 instance. I guess that you are connecting to a SQL Server 2005 instance and that you get this message:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

Check the version of your SQL Server instance with `select @@version`.